# why it producing duplicate results at first time binding in radgrid i'm sharing my sql server results hope you understand my issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, radgrid

in sql script it is producing duplicate results [https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ZSj.png[1]  at the firsttime binding

Comment: The fact that you have no badges shows that you ignored the prompt to take the site tour when you registered and the standard of your question backs that up. Please read at least [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then fix your question to a standard that is acceptable.

Comment: You will have to share the code that produces the duplicate results.